# Spring controller request mappings aren't being recognized

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc

I've been working on a side project for a while and I'm still somewhat new to the spring framework.  I noticed that when I compile the web application on a tomcat server the request mappings are never being recognized.  I've made sure that the component scan xml tags are being used, but I'm not sure where else to look for why they aren't being loaded.  Here's the link to the github project:

http://github.com/dmcquillan314/YouthMinistryHibernate.git

As requested here's my web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>YouthMinistryHibernate</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
        <param-value>simple</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
            <param-value>simple</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my spring-mvc.xml files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.youthministry.controller"  />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>message</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Let me know if I need to post anything further.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check out you project for my local problem, Below link explains different kind of config tag you may use such as `mvc:annotation-drive ,context component-scan` and so on.

[Different Spring Annotation XML Declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038830/different-spring-annotation-xml-declarations)

And I also recommend you to add log4j to the project, then set the log level to debug. so that when you start up the project it can print out all the url that in the @RequestMapping and when you send request to the server, it also can print out the url that you send, so you can find the problem easily.

Comment: I added in the config for the annotations and they still don't seem to be recognized.  I'm running it via eclipse.

Comment: did you add @Controller to you controller class?

Comment: Another thing is that you servlet name is "appServlet", so your config xml name should be appServlet-mvc.xml, not spring-mvc.xml

Answer (score 1):

What does your web.xml look like?  (Maybe you could post the relevant config files directly on this post....)  Paths have to be specified to be "picked up".

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

```
<web-app>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/example/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your context xml file, you have added component scan tag. But one tag is missing which enables application to read annotation.

```
<annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.youthministry.controller" />
```

Try adding the missing tag.